# Add fields to TYPO3 template for global site info?

Tags: typo3, typoscript, fluid, typo3-9.x

How can I add some fields to the TYPO3 template (or a better location) for general site info?

For example, a phone number field so that I can add it to the site header or other non content area.

In the past I have used content elements in a special folder to add something like this, but that's not very user friendly for site editors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it to be (relatively) easy for site editors to edit, without building a custom module or something like that, content elements in a special folder is your best bet. We often use custom content elements for this so the field are more logical, but you do need to do some programming for this. More on creating custom fields can be found at https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/ContentElements/AddingYourOwnContentElements.html

An alternative could be using a TypoScript constant. These are relatively easy to edit using the Constants editor in the Template module. Assuming you use Fluid templates, you can add it to your template with `<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.phoneNumber" />` In TypoScript you then add the following:

```
lib.phoneNumber = TEXT
lib.phoneNumber.value = {$phoneNumber}
```

More about the Constants editor can be found at https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/master/en-us/UsingSetting/TheConstantEditor.html

Answer (score 1):

in both other answers I miss the simplest solution:
defining the value as a generic fluid variable

```
page {
    10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
    10 {
        :
        variables {
            :
            phoneNumber = TEXT
            phoneNumber.value = {$phoneNumber}
        }
    }
}
```

You do not need to use `settings` as it is no setting.
or jumping back from fluid to typoscript with `lib.anything` and a call to `f:cObject` viewhelper.

---

Aside of that I would recommend to consider if it is ok to need an admin (or even a maintainer to deploy a new version) to change that phone number (all typoscript, setup and constants, belongs into the site-extensions which is provided in a repository).

you always could restrict normal editors from accessing special pages or even columns or special content elements, where an admin can change data without a deploy-process.
(example: How much hassle it is if you need to change the number in case of emergency because of a breakdown of phone lines?)

Comment: Adding new fields in the Constant Editor is the closest to what I was looking for. But your suggestion is good for how to use that field data, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to add it with TS, something like that :

```
page {
   10 {
      settings {
         siteInfos {
            phone = 01 02 03 04 05
         }
      }
   }
}
```

And then , you can use this in you Fluid Templates :

```
{settings.siteInfos.phone}
```

Florian